# Plain enumeration of theorems definitions etc

Tags: numbering, environments, theorems

In my TeX document Theorems, Definitions, Lemmas are enumerated in the following way:

```
Definition 1.1

Lemma 1.1

Theorem 1.1

Definition 1.2

Lemma 1.2

Theorem 1.2
```

But I would like to have

```
Definition 1.1

Lemma 1.2

Theorem 1.3

Definition 1.4

Lemma 1.5

Theorem 1.6
```

How can I obtain this?

Edit. The begin of my document is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{amsthm}


\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}[section]

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]



\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
```

Comment: What package are you using to generate these environments? Are you defining them without packages? Either way, include these in your post via an [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/50621/edit).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Seconding Werner's comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: very similar to (possible duplicate?) [common-per-section-numbering-of-theorems-lemmas-etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17619/common-per-section-numbering-of-theorems-lemmas-etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the first optional argument, that denotes the counter to share:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
```