# Using \newtheorem

Tags: numbering, theorems

Edited to include complete code, as suggested:

Here is what the preamble of my main file looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{upmathgrad2}  
\usepackage{UPnotations}
\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx, amsmath, amsthm}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[thm]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[thm]
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[thm]
\newtheorem{ill}{Illustration}[thm]
```

I've been trying to tinker on ways to change the above code however I still get the following numbering:

```
Chapter 1
1.1 Section A
Definition 1.0.1
Theorem 1.0.2
Theorem 1.0.3
```

The definitions, theorems, lemmas, etc. are numbered continuously as I wanted. However, I wanted to get rid of the 0's. How do I do this?

I tried to use the suggestions in this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17619/common-per-section-numbering-of-theorems-lemmas-etc) however things just got worse.

For example, when I tried:

```
\newcounter{dummy} \numberwithin{dummy}{section}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[dummy]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[dummy]
```

I got Definition 1.1.0.1 instead.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: I've upadated my answer. Is it something like that what you want? If not, please explain clearly the desired numbering scheme.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `\newtheorem` command has two *mutually exlusive* optional arguments:

Using

```
\newtheorem{<name>}{<heading>}[<counter>]
```

will create an environment `<name>` for a theorem-like structure; the counter for this structure will be subordinated to `<counter>`. On the other hand, using

```
\newtheorem{<name>}[<counter>]{<heading>}
```

will create an environment `<name>` for a theorem-like structure; the counter for this structure will share the previously defined `<counter>` counter.

In the definition of `defn` you need to use the *first* optional argument of `\newtheorem` to indicate that this environment shares the counter of the previously defined `thm` environment.

If the counters need to be subordinate to the `section` counter, use `section` for the second optional argument of `\newtheorem` in the definition of `thm`. A little example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\begin{defn}test\end{defn}
\begin{thm}test\end{thm}
\begin{thm}test\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if the counters need to be subordinate to the `chapter` counter, use `chapter` for the second optional argument of `\newtheorem` in the definition of `thm`. A little example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\begin{defn}test\end{defn}
\begin{thm}test\end{thm}
\begin{thm}test\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar remark applies to the other structures; so instead of

```
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[thm]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[thm]
...
```

you probablly want

```
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ill}[thm]{Illustration}
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I get the following:

1.1 Test

Definition 1.1

Theorem 1.1.1

Instead of Definition 1.1.1.

Comment: @Kenjo please see my updated answer.

Comment: I just edited the file just as you wrote. Here's what I get.

1.1 Test
Denition 1.1.Test
Lemma 1.1.1.Test
Theorem 1.2.Test
Remark 1.2.1.Test
Illustration 1.2.1. Test
Corollary 1.2.1.Test

Something is

Comment: @Kenjo as I mentioned in the last part of my answer, you have to change all the other theorem structures as well.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks a lot it's now numbered the way I wanted it.

Comment: Just for reference: See also Barbara Beeton’s great answer: [Understanding the arguments in newtheorem e.g. \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}\[section\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155714).

Comment: I agree that Barbara Beeton's answer is also great! Note that their answer does not cover the mutually exclusive parametrization, specifically the subordinate form.