# Common numbering with ntheorem

Tags: numbering, theorems, ntheorem

I have the exact same question as detailed in [Common, per-section numbering of theorems, lemmas etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17619/common-per-section-numbering-of-theorems-lemmas-etc), but I am using `ntheorem` and so can't use the accepted answers code. Does anyone know how to adapt this to the case of `ntheorem`? Thanks!

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,thmtools,amscd}

\usepackage{eucal}

\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newcounter{dummy} \numberwithin{dummy}{section}


\theoremprework{\setlength
\theorempreskipamount{10 pt}\setlength\theorempostskipamount{10 pt}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[dummy][subsection]

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacklozenge}}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[dummy][subsection]

\theoremprework{\setlength\theorempreskipamount{10 pt}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[dummy][subsection]

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[dummy][subsection]


\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape \bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[dummy][subsection]

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape \bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[dummy][subsection]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} Hey
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}I
\end{lemma}
 
\begin{prop}Just
\end{prop}

\begin{remark}Met
\end{remark}

\begin{example}You
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

At the end I would like it to look something like

> 1 First Section
>
> 1.1 First Subsection
>
> Theorem 1.1.1
>
> Proposition 1.1.2
>
> Lemma 1.1.3
>
> 1.2 Second Subsection
>
> Theorem 1.2.1
>
> Proposition 1.2.2
>
> Lemma 1.2.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your code, it seems that you want each of the `theorem-like` environments to inherit the `subsection` counter. As such, I have used

```
\newcounter{dummy} 
\numberwithin{dummy}{subsection}
```

in the below.

Note that you can use

```
\newtheorem{example}[dummy]{Example}
```

which tells the `newtheorem` command to make the `example` counter inherit the `dummy` counter, but not

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[dummy][subsection]
```

as this is undefined.

[image: screenshot]

Here's the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newcounter{dummy}
\numberwithin{dummy}{subsection}

\theoremprework{\setlength
\theorempreskipamount{10 pt}\setlength\theorempostskipamount{10 pt}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{example}[dummy]{Example}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacklozenge}}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{remark}[dummy]{Remark}

\theoremprework{\setlength\theorempreskipamount{10 pt}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{theorem}[dummy]{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{prop}[dummy]{Proposition}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape \bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{corollary}[dummy]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape \bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{lemma}[dummy]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{SubSection}
\begin{theorem} Hey
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}I
\end{lemma}

\begin{prop}Just
\end{prop}

\begin{remark}Met
\end{remark}

\begin{example}You
\end{example}

\subsection{SubSection}
\begin{theorem} Hey
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}I
\end{lemma}

\begin{prop}Just
\end{prop}

\begin{remark}Met
\end{remark}

\begin{example}You
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works!...almost. It makes my theorems come out like theorem 1.1.0.1 instead of 1.1.1.

Comment: @cmhughest That still isn't exact right. I've edited my original post with what I would like the outcome to look like. Thanks so much!

Comment: @AlexYoucis see the update :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis you're welcome :) Your question is now *very* clear- remember to make future questions as clear at the beginning :)

Answer (score 6):

This does not require introduction of new counters at all.  `\newtheorem` has two syntaxes

```
\newtheorem{myname}{Heading}[countwithin]
```

and

```
\newtheorem{myname}[usecounter]{Heading}
```

So if you set up your first theorem definition to be counted within `subsection`, and then tell the other environments to use the counter of your first environment you will get the desired numbering.  Here is a cut down version of the code with irrelevant formatting etc. removed:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]
\newtheorem{remark}[example]{Remark}
\newtheorem{theorem}[example]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}[example]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[example]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[example]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{theorem}
  Theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}
  Proposition
\end{prop}

\begin{lemma}
  Lemma
\end{lemma}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\begin{theorem}
  Theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}
  Proposition
\end{prop}

\begin{lemma}
  Lemma
\end{lemma}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{Next subsection}

\begin{theorem}
  Theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}
  Proposition
\end{prop}

\begin{lemma}
  Lemma
\end{lemma}

\subsection{Last subsection}

\begin{theorem}
  Theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{prop}
  Proposition
\end{prop}

\begin{lemma}
  Lemma
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today and found a different solutions having some advantages as well as some disadvantages.

In the *ntheorem.std* file the most common environments like "theorem", "lemma", "definition" etc. are already defined in English and in German (see the [ntheorem documentation](https://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf)).

You should find *ntheorem.std* in your package repository. For me it was: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ntheorem"

There it says

```
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
...
```

So just change those commands to

```
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{theorem}[Theorem]{Theorem}
...
```

or whatever numbering you like.

Edit: I forgot that when you want to use those standard environments you have to tell Latex to include ntheorem with the standard option.

```
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
```