# Do not get a square ntheorem, proof

Tags: amsmath, ntheorem

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\newtheorem{Beweis}{Beweis}

\begin{document}

\begin{Beweis}
\begin{align*}
test
\end{align*}
\end{Beweis}
\end{document}
```

But no matter what I do I do not get a square at the end of the proof. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! It should probably be `amssymb` and not `amsymbol`

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\newtheorem{Beweis}{Beweis}


\begin{document}

\begin{Beweis}
gwe
\end{Beweis}

\end{document}` gives me a square at the end.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{Beweis}{Beweis}

\begin{document}

\begin{Beweis}
Sample Text
\end{Beweis}

\end{document}

Gives me no square

Comment: How are you compiling? I tried with pdflatex from texlive2017.

Comment: i use sharelatex...

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59fb3f5eebcd6470de6753b0 seems to work fine.

Comment: Maybe this helps you to get my problem. I tried using this, but since this has no Proof enviroment i had to make my own. But i am really bad with Latex (started a week ago) just for this project
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99790/common-numbering-with-ntheorem

Comment: Can you share a link to your sharelatex project that shows your problem with the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399316/do-not-get-a-square-ntheorem-proof#comment993689_399316

Comment: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59fb41e62b588f29fdf49e51

Plus another question. Is there a possibility to remove the number after proof? So it is not "Beweis 1" just "Beweis"?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `amsthm`. The name of the proof will automatically be translated to "Beweis" thanks to the babel package and it solves your additional problem with the number you mentioned [in your comment][1.

Thanks to barbara beeton for the [hint with the qed symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399316/do-not-get-a-square-ntheorem-proof/399324?noredirect=1#comment993775_399324)!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Es ist (geometrische Reihe):
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^k=&\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}\\
    =&\frac{4}{3}\\
    \iff \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^k=&\frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
Und damit ist bei nur n Viertelungen:
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^k+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^k=&\frac{1}{3}\\
    \iff \sum_{k=1}^{n}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^k=&\frac{1}{3}-\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^k\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that Theorem's won't count with my subsections anymore. Or is it not possible to have both, theorems like in 
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59fb41e62b588f29fdf49e51
and a proof with a square?

Comment: @TomGöbel Not sure what you mean by "won't count with my subsections", but you can set up theorem numbering within subsection, have a look at the documentation http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf

Comment: The theorem in sharelatex.com/project/59fb41e62b588f29fdf49e51 gets the number of its subsection "Satz 2.1.1".
With your code that doesn't work anymore. So i got one problem fixed but got a new one.

Comment: the square really ought to be on the last line of the final display.  with `amsthm`, you can make that happen by inserting `\qedhere` before the final `\end{align}`.  (documented in the `amsthm` user's guide.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for the advice! I edited my answer.